# display the week number of a date in phpexcel

Tags: phpexcel

may I know how to display the week number of a date in phpexcel ??

```
 $objPHPExcel->getActiveSheet()->setCellValue('AC1', "=WEEKNUM(I30,2)");
```

my code above dint work. is it any syntax error??

Comment: The WEEKNUM function should work. Can you let me know what value you have in cell I30, and what you're actually getting in cell AC1.

Comment: Also, what Writer are you using? WEEKNUM isn't supported for Excel5 because it was part of the analysis toolpack, not a core Excel function.

Comment: $date2 = new DateTime($row['latestDeliveryDate']);
$objPHPExcel->getActiveSheet()->setCellValue('I30', $date2->format('d-M-y'));

Comment: my cell I30 is retrieve the date from database value.

Comment: i am using Excel5.But it cannot function.

Comment: Even if you're using Excel5, you can still use the code that calculates the weeknum to get the week number, and then set that result value in the cell

Comment: My code not work in my program .nothings error specify and the column AC1 is blank.

Comment: You're right! As I said, it doesn't write the formula to Excel5 spreadsheets because WEEKNUM isn't a core function in Excel5 spreadsheets. There is no error, and the cell is saved as a blank cell. It will work with the Excel2007 Writer, because it is a core function in Excel2007

Comment: ok~~understand wht u mean ady. I have change it to Excel2007 writer ,it work. Thanks very much.

Comment: may i ask u another question?? since i change it to Excel2007 writer,another problem for date is appear. Below is my code.               first ,i will retrieve date from database,and set it to cell AA12.                            $date = new DateTime($row['date']);
$objPHPExcel->getActiveSheet()->setCellValue('AA12', $date->format('d-M-y'));

Comment: after that ,i have another column which refer to AA12.  $objPHPExcel->getActiveSheet()->setCellValue('I'.$datecol,'=AA12+7');
$objPHPExcel->getActiveSheet()->getStyle('I'.$datecol)->getNumberFormat()->setFormatCode(PHPExcel_Style_NumberFormat::FORMAT_DATE_XLSX15);     the result will display 0.But it work in Excel5. Do u know wht is going wrong?Thx

Answer (score 0):

Here's the WeekNum method from the [office suite website](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/bb224768%28v=office.12%29.aspx). As long as you're setting the arguments properly and using a valid DATE, you should be okay.

Actually, after looking through the PHPExcel 1.7.8 documentation (Function Reference, page 39), it appears the WEEKNUM function is not supported.

Comment: i have look through PHPExcel Function Reference
Developer Documentation.It also dint mention about tis weeknum function.so sad......any solution to solve it?

Comment: Note that there is a difference between not documented and not supported. WEEKNUM is supported, but only in Excel2007 format files